# I don't understand this error on map insert

Tags: c++, dictionary, functional-programming

```
//Menu.h

#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;
map<string,function< void() > > mapa;
string names[100];
string functions[100];
char keys[100];
int pos=0;

void menu(string name,char key,string functionc)
{
    names[pos]=name;
    keys[pos]=key;
    functions[pos]=functionc;
    mapa.insert(map<string,function< void()> >::value_type(functionc,functionc));
    pos++;
}

void write()
{
    for(int i=0;i<pos;i++)
    {
        cout<<names[pos]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

> ERROR: Error  1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function
>   taking 0 arguments

```
//Main.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    #include <string>

    #include"Menu.h"
    using namespace std;

    void ime()
    {
    cout<<"k";
    }

    int main() {
    menu("ime1",'c',"ime");
    pisi();

    system("PAUSE");
      return 0;
    }
```

I want to make the header generic so the user can make a menu.
it will cout its name and which char is needed to be pressed to access it's function
the user will make it's own function then from the header it needs to use it....

Comment: One nice thing about Visual Studio is that you can look up what all the error codes mean (C2064 in this case). Just search for "MSDN C2064".

Comment: Please don't put using namespace std; in a header. In fact, please don't put much of this code in a header

Comment: ok i ll make a new file cpp then include it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can make your code compile by changing it thus:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;
map<string,string > mapa;
string names[100];
string functions[100];
char keys[100];
int pos=0;
void menu(string name,char key,string functionc)
{

    names[pos]=name;
    keys[pos]=key;
    functions[pos]=functionc;
    mapa.insert(std::make_pair(functionc,functionc));
    pos++;
}
void write()
{
    for(int i=0;i<pos;i++)
    {
        cout<<names[pos]<<" ";

        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

I am worried by the menu.h comment at the top - is this a header file?
Now, that has sorted the compile error, but probably doesn't do what you want. Do you want a map of names to functions?

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> strings_to_functions;
```

With a function taking no parameters and returning void, for example

```
void fn1()
{
    std::cout << "fn1\n";
}
```

I can now add it to the map,

```
strings_to_functions.insert(std::make_pair("fn1", fn1));
```

and call it

```
strings_to_functions["fn1"]();
```

Comment: ye i know that anyway the make_pair did the thing ty

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't support this. You'd need a programming language property called *reflection*.

Use a scripting language instead.

Answer (score 1):

You arre attempting to make an `std::function<void()>` from an `std::string` here:

```
map<string,function< void()> >::value_type(functionc,functionc)
        //                                           ^^^^^^^^^
```

You need to pass something that is callable with no arguments, returning `void`. For example:

```
void foo() {};

mapa.insert(std::make_pair(functionc, foo));
```

Comment: and then insert the map's value type, rather than a std::pair

Comment: yeah i know is there a solution or a better way for this?

Comment: Add functions to the map, or change the map to std::map<std::string, std::string>.

Comment: @HahahaHahaha what do you mean a solution better than this? What are you trying to do? A string is not callable.

Comment: yeah but i want to include the function from the main menu so it will be generic

Comment: this is menu.h i want from the .cpp which contains the main()

Comment: @HahahaHahaha that is a different question. I am answering the question you asked.

Comment: @HahahaHahaha I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @HahahaHahaha: Please don't edit it so much that it changes meaning entirely.

Comment: @HahahaHahaha you may be better off asking a different question.

Answer (score 0):

```
//MENU.h
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;
map<string,function< void() > > mapa;
string names[100];
string functions[100];
char keys[100];
int pos=0;

void menu(string name,char key, function< void() >functionc)
{
    names[pos]=name;
    keys[pos]=key;
    functions[pos]=functionc;
    mapa.insert(std::make_pair(name,functionc));
    pos++;
}

//Main.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    #include <string>

    #include"Menu.h"
    using namespace std;

    void ime()
    {
    cout<<"k";
    }

    int main() {
    menu("ime1",'c', ime);
    pisi();

    system("PAUSE");`enter code here`
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is not an answer, just a code dump. Please explain *why* and *how* it solves the problems the OP faced.

Comment: Why: Because the map<string, function<void>> need a function with no return and no arguments as value, so you must insert on the map a function< void() > functionc and not a string functionc

Comment: You should explain this (when it doubt, at length) in your answer. That's what answers are for. Not for dumping code *without explanation*. Since you seem able to provide the explanation, why don't you edit it in? It'll even earn you a badge. (=

Comment: Thanks for your advice. That answer was my first answer in community like this on the internet. And sorry for my english, i'm not a native speaker.

Comment: You're welcome (on SO). People honestly trying their best and putting in effort to become better are always nice to have around. (=

Comment: I'm not a native speaker either. Just do your best and if you manage to do well enough that you can be understood, someone will probably edit it in shape. (You should always look at the edits people do to your question. Some edits are worthless but most of them are sensible and you can learn a lot from studying them.)